# Laravel PHPUnit always passes CSRF

Tags: php, laravel, phpunit

I'm currently writing a test to assure that our CSRF protection works in Laravel. The test looks like this.

```
public function testSecurityIncorrectCSRF()
{
    $this->visit('/login')
     ->type('REDACTED', 'email')
     ->type('123123', 'password');

     session()->regenerateToken();

     $this->press('login')
     ->seePageIs('/login');
}
```

No matter what I do, and even if I pass a wrong _token, the login request will always succeed. I've tried outside of the PHPUnit test and there the CSRF protection works. All my middlewares are enabled, so the CSRF protection should be enabled.

Can anybody explain why this happens?

Comment: Have you modified the default `App\Http\kernel.php` file and moved the `web` middleware somewhere else?

Comment: `protected $middlewareGroups = [
        'web' => [
            \Illuminate\Session\Middleware\StartSession::class,
            \App\Http\Middleware\VerifyCsrfToken::class,
        ]]`

Comment: It's basically the original Kernel, just with some extra Middlewares

Comment: Did you ever find out a way to do this? I see the answer shows why it does not validate CSRF, but I too would like to run a test to make sure it works.

Comment: As far as I remember, the CSRF are enforced, if you set the environment to something other than test (fx. production)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Have a look at the `Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\VerifyCsrfToken` class, especially the `handle` method.

```
public function handle($request, Closure $next)
{
    if (
        $this->isReading($request) ||
        $this->runningUnitTests() ||
        $this->shouldPassThrough($request) ||
        $this->tokensMatch($request)
    ) {
        return $this->addCookieToResponse($request, $next($request));
    }

    throw new TokenMismatchException;
}
```

It always passes the csrf token check if it detects that the request comes from a unit test: `$this->runningUnitTests()`

A solution would be to put the following code at the start of your test-function:

```php
$this->app['env'] = 'production';
```

This will change the environment to production, thus enabling the csrf token check.

Comment: That's great. I think the other way is to extend VerifyCsrfToken for test and override the runningUnitTests function to return false. Then you test only with the middleware. This will not introduce side effects, because a test is still a test.